# Why collabrate a few DAGs into a big DAG before input GNN?

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-neural-network

When coding or modeling, is there any difference between inputing DAG into GNN one by one and collabrating a few DAGs into a big DAG before input GNN? Is there any influence to GNN training?

Thannk you for your code advice.